# How to add looped items from ItemTemplate into array

Tags: c#, arrays, episerver

I have a PageList with some data, and I want to add all Date's to an array as strings. Seems easy enough but I'm kinda new to this, so anyone out there who knows how to solve this?

```
<EPiServer:PageList ID="PageList1" runat="server" PageLinkProperty="Root">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><EPiServer:Property runat="server" PropertyName="Title" /></h2>
        <EPiServer:Property runat="server" PropertyName="Date" /><br />
        <EPiServer:Property runat="server" PropertyName="Content" />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</EPiServer:PageList>
```

Comment: Which EPi version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code that will work with any EPi verson. I know you wrote Dates as strings but I made a List of DateTimes instead.

```
var reference = (PageReference)CurrentPage["Root"];
var children = DataFactory.Instance.GetChildren(reference);
var list = new List<DateTime>();

foreach (PageData pd in children)
{
    list.Add((DateTime)pd["Date"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time helping me with this! This was very helpful